# Change the default CSS font for uikit

Tags: css, uikit, getuikit

Hoe do you change the default font for uikit? [UIKit](http://getuikit.com/)

The default font is

```
"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
```

and its set on the html element tag. If i change this font on my custom style in the html tag to something else it doesn't overwrite the changes. I can use important which does change things:

```
html {
     font: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
}
```

This changes the global font as expected **but** font-awesome obviously no longer works because the !important is over writing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is quite old but I'll post the current working answer anyway incase anyone else needs it for version 3 as [documented here](https://getuikit.com/docs/sass#create-a-uikit-theme):

```scss
// 1. Your custom variables and variable overwrites. If you are using google fonts,
//follow their instructions as normal as well. (add a link in the html for example).
$global-font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;

// 2. Import default variables and available mixins.
@import "../../node_modules/uikit/src/scss/variables-theme.scss";
@import "../../node_modules/uikit/src/scss/mixins-theme.scss";

// 3. Import UIkit.
@import "../../node_modules/uikit/src/scss/uikit-theme.scss";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the customizer from the uikit page. http://getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html See the Body font family, heading font family selects.

Or use scss/less version and have fun with uikit-variables.scss , there are variables $base-body-font-family, $base-heading-font-family .

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is include a custom css file **after** uikit's css, whether you call uikit from a CDN or locally -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.18/css/uikit.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/templates/css/app.css" />
```

In your app.css do this

```
html{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

and you should be good to go. Font-Awesome should not be affected at all.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the easiest and maybe the cleanest way would be this. However, I'd be careful about the performance...

```
* { font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the new font-family in html works for me without adding `!important` or breaking fontawesome.

https://jsfiddle.net/95sff36a/

That said, I typically prefer making the edits on `body` tag such as this

```
body{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

**NOTE:** This doesn't take effect on headings, you might want to add them explicitly.